# iOS Revoked Certificate will affect push notification in the App Store?

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, certificate

So I know this has been asked probably a million times on here but I really need to be sure.

So I just joined a company and had to re-upload a new version to the iOS App store. Their certificates naming were all messy so I had to revoke some certificates to create new ones. Here are the ones I've revoked:

1. iOS development certificate
2. iOS development certificate
3. APNs Production iOS certificate
4. APNs Development iOS certificate

Right now, there is a version of the app currently on the App Store. And I just got word that push notifications stopped working. I'm assuming it is because I revoked the APNs Production iOS certificate (#3) that created this problem. Can someone confirm?

And most importantly, how can I save this situation *right now* instead of waiting for another week to wait for Apple to approve my app.

What I've done is created a new .p12 file for my server developers to upload. Does this solve the problem?

I also got this from Apple in an e-mail:

Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['BG67MH9xxx.com.xxx.xxx'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['H4T5TJUxxx.com.xxx.xxx']. This will result in a loss of keychain access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revoking application certificate will definitely change the application identifier. Revoked APNs certificate issue can be fixed by simply uploading a new CSR to generate a new push certificate and use that in your push notifications. This doesn't require a version uploaded to AppStore.